# How to implement QUIC Server Name Indication (SNI) Detection in c++?

Tags: c++, quic

I'm trying to write a function in c++ that will take UDP payload_buffer as an argument and return hostname used by the the QUIC session if the buffer contain the SNI.

It should be able to detect QUIC version compatible with 3 versions: Google QUIC Q043, Google QUIC Q046 and Google QUIC Q050.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrypt the initial packet. The salt of each Quic version might be different.
Suggest you to check the wireshark's source code.

A good article: https://blogs.keysight.com/blogs/tech/nwvs.entry.html/2021/07/17/looking_into_quicpa-pUtF.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32704703)